# Floyd's triangle with math, not strings

Tags: python, triangle

I'm looking at a challenge to build a Floyd's triangle out of integers using only arithmetic operators and a single for-loop.  There are hundreds of tutorials using dual for-loops and string operations, but I haven't seen anything using math.

Example output using repeating integers:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

I'm approaching the solution logic like so:

```
1 * (1) = 1
2 * (1 + 10) = 22
3 * (1 + 10 + 100) = 333
```

As a newb Python learner I can't construct the logic loop.  Any ideas or alternative approaches?  No string operations allowed here, just math!

Comment: If you use hex, you can go past 9 rows

Comment: When you're trying to convert some logic to a loop, think about how you can express the key logic of the loop as a function of the counter. For your example, you've recognized that you need to multiply the loop counter by some factor (1, 11, 111, ...), and you've recognized that 111 = 1 + 10 + 100. Next, note that `1 = 10**0`, `10 = 10**1`, `100 = 10**2`, and so on. This tells you that the `i`th line of your output is going to be `i * sum(10**x)`, where `x` goes from `0` to `i-1`

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Using sum(10**x) threw a 'not iterable' error since the input isn't an iterable list.  Also, the challenge forbids using more than one for-loop.  The solution from Benjamin Merchin does work.  But it's still more code than allowed by the challenge.  If I missed the concept of sum() let me know.  I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works for me :)

```
n = 4

val=0
for i in range(n):
    val+=10**i
    print(val*(i+1))
```

Val is 1, then 11, then 111. I'm not sure if this is what you are expecting.

Comment: Use base 16 and print `hex(val * (i + 1))` :)

Comment: The += approach works with a slight variation by using (i-1) as the power.  That results in 1*1 = 1 as the first number in the triangle.  A further part of the challenge is to get the code down to two lines, and this is four lines.  But it's way better than what I had before.

Comment: Interesting, you can do it in two lines like that:
`val=0` `for i in range(n):val+=10**i;print(val*(i+1))`

Comment: That did it!  I wasn't familiar with the semi-colon separator, so I just learned something new for making my code more compact.  Thanks, I appreciate that.